# Why doesn't this jQuery code moving divs to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PsQBD/) (with slightly modified values so it appears correctly).

I am trying to move the position of some divs on my page.

```
div.note {float:left;width:666px;  padding:0 0 0 50px;}
div.first_note {margin-left: 565px;}
```

The divs are horizontally displayed, with 50px between each one.

```
<div id="note-1" class="note first_note">
    note display here
</div>
<div id="note-2" class="note">
    note display here
</div>
<div id="note-3" class="note">
    note display here
</div>
```

This is the moving code:

```
$('.note').animate({"left": "+=500px"}, "slow");
```

When this is run, the notes don't move at all, but the HTML changes to this:

```
<div id="note-1" class="note first_note" style="left: 500px;">
    note display here
</div>
<div id="note-2" class="note" style="left: 500px;">
    note display here
</div>
<div id="note-3" class="note" style="left: 500px;">
    note display here
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to position it relative.

```
div.note {
    float:left;width:60px;  
    padding:0 0 0 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/uBtCh/)

Answer (score 0):

edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PsQBD/1/

it should be

```
margin-left: +=500
```

without the px.

Comment: take note, the OP uses `left` and not `margin-left`. px is not the problem here.Your demo even with the px, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/PsQBD/4/)